# How do I set the AndroidStudioProjects directory as the home directory in Android Studio on Windows 10 (64 bits)?

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I want to open an existing project, it puts me on the user directory and I have to navigate from there until I find the projects folder.

When I first downloaded Android Studio (3.3.2), the top left icon (with home icon) used to point me directly to the Android Projects folder but not anymore.